# C++ OOP how to write a function equivalent to "pointer to a pointer"?

Tags: c++

How do I write a class function that allows another function to modify a member through its pointer?

Ex:

```
class cFoo
{   private:
    char *m_bar;
    public:
    char *bar(void) {return m_bar;}
    void set_bar(char *newBar) {m_bar = newBar;}
};

void func2(char **c)
{    *c = malloc(256);
}

cFoo fooInst;
func2(&fooInst.m_bar);  // this will fail, but...
                        // how to do this with a function that references 'm_bar'?
```

I can't use `set_bar` because `func2` needs to be the one setting the value.

I am looking for a function of the class cFoo, that I can use to pass as an argument to another function, which needs to modify a member of cFoo.

Note: `char` and `malloc` are purely for illustration purposes, the actual case is much more complicated and has been simplified for the purpose of discussion. The actual code is legacy code, and we're trying to refactor it gradually and non-destructively.

Comment: The first big question here would be why you want code outside the class to directly manipulate a private data member of the class. That's usually a poor idea. Much of the point of making a member private is specifically to prevent that. Using `malloc` in C++ isn't usually a great idea either.

Comment: How does it fail, what is the error? I am getting `error C2628: 'cFoo' followed by 'void' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?` but it is not that line with `func2` call.

Comment: @273K: That's because of the missing `;` at the end of the definition of `class cFoo`.

Comment: @273K: I'm not assuming anything.

Comment: @273K These comments are visible to everyone. Stating why is not just to help you.

Comment: Aside from multiple unrelated syntax/type errors and design questions, returning the member by-pointer or by-reference from `bar` should be enough, right?

Comment: Another suggestion is to avoid some of your pointer gymnastics if you declared your function arguments by reference, e.g. `void func2(char& *c) { c = malloc(256); }`. Then you can just call it without the need for `&` in your call, e.g. `func2(fooInst.m_bar);`

Comment: @StephenQuan That's not OP's problem. The problem is that `m_bar` is `private` and so cannot be named at all in that context. The whole pointer thing is a red herring.

Comment: PSA: You don't need to declare functions as `f(void)`, in C++ that's assumed for `f()`. You should also use `new[]` instead of malloc, or better yet, *avoid pointers* whenever possible. For example, what's stopping you from using `std::string` here instead?

Comment: Since `m_bar` is a `private` member, the call `func2(&fooInst.m_bar)` is not permitted, unless in code that is a member or `friend` of `cFoo`.    Your choices include (1) only call `func2(&fooInst.m_bar)` from a member or declared `friend` of `cFoo`  or (2)  change the access of `m_bar` from `private` to `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very poor design, you can do a such thing:

```
    // ...
    char*& bar() { return m_bar; }
    // ...

func2(&fooInst.bar());
```

A bit better:

```
cFoo fooInst;
char* bar = nullptr;
func2(&bar);
fooInst.set_bar(bar);
```

Let omit issues with storing an unmanaged raw pointer.

Comment: `char*&` did the trick. Thank you. As for "poor design", this program was started in 1995 for Windows 3.1, 16-bit. It has run on millions of desktops, and has evolved by careful, incremental refactoring into a 64-bit program that runs on macOS as well as Windows. Still going strong  :o)